# What is the difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost in regards to cookies

Tags: express, sockets, networking, cookies, localhost

I run a frontend  client that uses React and communicates with a local backend using express. I tried viewing the cookies in my browser and I had a weird issue:

When I connect using 127.0.0.1, I don't see cookies on the browser. However, when I connect to localhost, (or when I use anything else like postman) I manage to get and view the cookies.

I'm having a hard time understanding why that is.

I've looked onto other questions that ask the difference on these two, and If I understand correctly, 127.0.0.1 is more direct since you don't need to lookup DNS to get the IP (unlike localhost)

Howevere, this still doesn't tell me why my cookies behave so weirdly on 127.0.0.1.

For more information, I've set "sameSite:None, secure:true", and I have cors enabled. Everything else works correctly with my connection, the only issue is when I go to the site "127.0.0.1:5173" instead of "localhost:5173"

Comment: Cookies are shared based on the domain name, or if it is explicitly defined as `withCredentials` for example when creating an HXR request.
127.0.0.1 is the default loopback address, and the localhost is rerouted to the loopback address. When creating a server, you can specify which interface to listen. By default is `localhost` or the routed loopback `127.0.0.1`

Comment: From the perspective of the browser these are different things - cookies set on a localhost URL are not reflected to 127.0.0.1 and vice versa. This is the same with any other domain name and its IP address. Also, different domains are treated as separat no matter if the resolve to the same IP address or not.

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff `localhost` is the DNS name of 127.0.0.1. Nothing to do with rerouting. There is no default listening address other than perhaps 0.0.0.0.